# How can I overrule/change and then reset a Binding?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a Canvas whose Width & Height are databound, e.g. Width:
`Width="{Binding DrawingSize.Width, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"`.
When I set the Canvas's Width somewhere in code behind to another value, the Binding is lost.
Can somebody explain why that is or where MSDN explains it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN explains this in the [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#resources):

> Dynamic resources and bindings have the precedence of where they were
>   set, but the value is deferred. One consequence of this is that if you
>   set a dynamic resource or binding to a local value, any change to the
>   local value replaces the dynamic resource or binding entirely.

You can use [SetCurrentValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to change the current value without overriding anything. However, even if there are valid usages for this method, I personally wouldn't recommend it. You're likely to run into other problems such as "who set this value, that's not the one I expected", or "the binding has changed too early, I lost my current value". Consider using the coercion mechanism, described in the same MSDN page, instead.